# word guessing game play again doesn't work

Tags: python

So basically after players win or lose, they would get to choose a different gamemode or the same gamemode to play again.

Here's 4 things that are supposed to happen:

- player type 1 and play normal guessing game
- player type 2 and play guessing game but with infinite guesses
- player type 3 and play guessing game but with 1 guess
- player type 4 and quit

But when I type 1, it restarts the game but I instantly lose cause the guesses did not reset, here's the error log

```
(1) Play guessing game
(2) Infinite mode
(3) Hardcore mode
(Q) Quit
Enter your choice: 1
Your word is one of these: ['ant', 'baboon', 'badger', 'bat', 'bear', 'beaver', 'camel', 'cat', 'clam', 'cobra', 'cougar', 'coyote', 'crow', 'deer', 'dog', 'donkey', 'duck', 'eagle', 'ferret', 'fox', 'frog', 'goat', 'goose', 'hawk', 'lion', 'lizard', 'llama', 'mole', 'monkey', 'moose', 'mouse', 'mule', 'newt', 'otter', 'owl', 'panda', 'parrot', 'pigeon', 'python', 'rabbit', 'ram', 'rat', 'raven', 'rhino', 'salmon', 'seal', 'shark', 'sheep', 'skunk', 'sloth', 'snake', 'spider', 'stork', 'swan', 'tiger', 'toad', 'trout', 'turkey', 'turtle', 'weasel', 'whale', 'wolf', 'wombat', 'zebra']
You have chosen a/an 3-letter word.
Enter a letter: m
Bad guess :(
---
Guesses left: 4
Available letters: A B C D E F G H I J K L N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z.
Enter a letter: k
Bad guess :(
---
Guesses left: 3
Available letters: A B C D E F G H I J L N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z.
Enter a letter: u
Bad guess :(
---
Guesses left: 2
Available letters: A B C D E F G H I J L N O P Q R S T V W X Y Z.
Enter a letter: r
Bad guess :(
---
Guesses left: 1
Available letters: A B C D E F G H I J L N O P Q S T V W X Y Z.
Enter a letter: o
Bad guess :(
---
Guesses left: 0
Available letters: A B C D E F G H I J L N P Q S T V W X Y Z.
You ran out of guesses. YOU LOST! The answer is BAT
(1) Play guessing game
(2) Infinite mode
(3) Hardcore mode
(Q) Quit
Enter your choice: 1
Your word is one of these: ['ant', 'baboon', 'badger', 'bat', 'bear', 'beaver', 'camel', 'cat', 'clam', 'cobra', 'cougar', 'coyote', 'crow', 'deer', 'dog', 'donkey', 'duck', 'eagle', 'ferret', 'fox', 'frog', 'goat', 'goose', 'hawk', 'lion', 'lizard', 'llama', 'mole', 'monkey', 'moose', 'mouse', 'mule', 'newt', 'otter', 'owl', 'panda', 'parrot', 'pigeon', 'python', 'rabbit', 'ram', 'rat', 'raven', 'rhino', 'salmon', 'seal', 'shark', 'sheep', 'skunk', 'sloth', 'snake', 'spider', 'stork', 'swan', 'tiger', 'toad', 'trout', 'turkey', 'turtle', 'weasel', 'whale', 'wolf', 'wombat', 'zebra']
You have chosen a/an 5-letter word.
You ran out of guesses. YOU LOST! The answer is WHALE
(1) Play guessing game
(2) Infinite mode
(3) Hardcore mode
(Q) Quit
Enter your choice:
```

Here's my full game code:

```
import random as r
import math
from time import sleep

guesses = 5
guesses_inf = ("infinite")
guesses_hard = 1
letters = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')


def format_word(guessed_letters, word):
    formatted_string = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed_letters:
            formatted_string += letter
        else:
            formatted_string += '-'
    return formatted_string

#display guessing game
def display_info(guessed_letters, word):
    available_letters = ' '.join([
        letter for letter in letters if letter not in guessed_letters
    ])
    print(format_word(guessed_letters, word))
    print(f"Guesses left: {guesses}")
    print(f"Available letters: {available_letters}.")

#check guess 
def check_guess(guess, word, guessed_letters):
    global guesses
    if guess in letters and len(guess) == 1 and guess not in guessed_letters:
        guessed_letters.append(guess)
        if guess in word:
            print("Good guess!")
        else:
            print("Bad guess :(")
            guesses -= 1
    else:
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("You can only enter one letter at a time!")
        elif guess.upper() not in letters:
            print("Your guess has to be a letter!")
        elif guess in guessed_letters:
            print("You have already tried this!")
    display_info(guessed_letters, word)

def can_be_formed_from(letters, word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letters:
            return False
    return True

#play game
def play_game():
    word_list = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()
    secret_word = r.choice(word_list).upper()
    word_length = len(secret_word)
    guessed = []
    print(f"Your word is one of these: {word_list}")
    print(f"You have chosen a/an {word_length}-letter word.")
    while guesses > 0:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
        check_guess(guess, secret_word, guessed)
        if can_be_formed_from(guessed, secret_word):
            return print("YOU WON!")
    print(f"You ran out of guesses. YOU LOST! The answer is {secret_word}")

#INFINITE GAMEMODE

#display info infinite
def display_info_inf(guessed_letters, word):
    available_letters = ' '.join([
        letter for letter in letters if letter not in guessed_letters
    ])
    print(format_word(guessed_letters, word))
    print("Guesses left: infinite")
    print(f"Available letters: {available_letters}.")

    
#check guesses infinite
def check_guess_inf(guess, word, guessed_letters):
    global guesses_inf
    if guess in letters and len(guess) == 1 and guess not in guessed_letters:
        guessed_letters.append(guess)
        if guess in word:
            print("Good guess!")
        else:
            print("Bad guess :(")
    else:
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("You can only enter one letter at a time!")
        elif guess.upper() not in letters:
            print("Your guess has to be a letter!")
        elif guess in guessed_letters:
            print("You have already tried this!")
    display_info_inf(guessed_letters, word)

def can_be_formed_from(letters, word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letters:
            return False
    return True
    
    
    
#play_game infinite
def play_game_infinite():
    word_list = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()
    secret_word = r.choice(word_list).upper()
    word_length = len(secret_word)
    guessed = []
    print(f"You have chosen a/an {word_length}-letter word.")
    while guesses_inf:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
        check_guess_inf(guess, secret_word, guessed)
        if can_be_formed_from(guessed, secret_word):
            return print("YOU WON!")

#Hardcore game start here

#display info hard
def display_info_hard(guessed_letters, word):
    available_letters = ' '.join([
        letter for letter in letters if letter not in guessed_letters
    ])
    print(format_word(guessed_letters, word))
    print(f"Guesses left: {guesses_hard}")

    
#check guesses infinite
def check_guess_hard(guess, word, guessed_letters):
    global guesses_hard
    if guess in letters and len(guess) == 1 and guess not in guessed_letters:
        guessed_letters.append(guess)
        if guess in word:
            ask = input("Is this your final answer?(y/n): ")
            if ask == "y":
                print("Good guess!")
            else:
                return play_game_hard()
        else:
            ask = input("Is this your final answer?(y/n): ")
            if ask == "y":
                print("Oops :(")
                guesses_hard -= 1
    else:
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("You can only enter one letter at a time!")
        elif guess.upper() not in letters:
            print("Your guess has to be a letter!")
        elif guess in guessed_letters:
            print("You have already tried this!")
    display_info_hard(guessed_letters, word)

def can_be_formed_from(letters, word):
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letters:
            return False
    return True

    
#play_game hard
def play_game_hard():
    word_list = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()
    secret_word = r.choice(word_list).upper()
    word_length = len(secret_word)
    guessed = []
    print(f"You have chosen a/an {word_length}-letter word.")
    while guesses_hard:
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
        check_guess_hard(guess, secret_word, guessed)
        if can_be_formed_from(guessed, secret_word):
            return print("YOU'RE A GENIUS or is it luck?")
    print(f"YOU LOST! The answer is {secret_word}")
    
    
def menu():
    while True:
        print("(1) Play guessing game")
        print("(2) Infinite mode")
        print("(3) Hardcore mode")
        print("(Q) Quit")
        choice = input("Enter your choice: ").lower()
        if choice == "1":
            play_game()
        elif choice == "2":
            print("IN BETA")
            sleep(1.00)
            play_game_infinite()
        elif choice == "3":
            print("IN BETA")
            sleep(1.00)
            play_game_hard()
        elif choice == "q":
            return False
        else:
            print(f"Not a correct choice: {choice}")
            

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

in the menu function, reset the guesses:

```
def menu():
    global guesses
    while True:
        print("(1) Play guessing game")
        print("(2) Infinite mode")
        print("(3) Hardcore mode")
        print("(Q) Quit")
        choice = input("Enter your choice: ").lower()
        if choice == "1":
            guesses = 5
            play_game()
        elif choice == "2":
            print("IN BETA")
            sleep(1.00)
            play_game_infinite()
        elif choice == "3":
            print("IN BETA")
            sleep(1.00)
            play_game_hard()
        elif choice == "q":
            return False
        else:
            print(f"Not a correct choice: {choice}")
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: it works perfectly on my computer. did you add the global guesses to the beginning of the menu function?

Comment: Oh I was missing global guesses at the beginning of the menu function that’s why it didn’t work thank you so much!